# How to wait for the rest of the daily ADF pipeline to continue once it reaches 3PM UTC

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a certain Stored procedure Activity part of the Daily pipeline(which triggers daily 7am) flow which should WAIT and continue its execution at a certain time of the day(like 3PM UTC) and also dependent on completion of another Stored Procedure Activity.

The Second condition of completion of dependent Stored Procedure Activity is just to introduce a dependency link. But the Waiting till it reaches 3PM i believe i cant achieve through a WAIT Activity/Validation Activity or Until Activity.

Can you please add your comments if the above possible activities can help my requirement or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AFAIK**, there is no limitation for the wait activity in ADF. You can use wait activity in this case.

First try the below approach as a sample.

First take a string variable `startdate` and store the `@utcnow()` value in it using set variable activity.

Then take your first stored procedure activity. After stored procedure activity, take wait activity.

Here for `8` hours (7 AM to 3 PM) we can give `28000` seconds for the wait activity. But we need to subtract the first stored procedure duration from it to execute the second procedure at correct time which is 3 PM.

Use the below expression, in the wait activity.

```
@sub(28800,int(div(sub(ticks(utcnow()), ticks(variables('start_date'))),10000000)))
```

[image]

After the wait activity take your second stored procedure activity.

In this sample try, **if you encounter any error regarding the threshold or limitation(seconds) of wait activity**, use multiple wait activities as per the limitation.

If it involves lot of wait activities, take a for loop(give `@range(1,<number of wait activities as per limit>)`) and use wait activities with threshold value limitation inside the loop. Add the second stored procedure activity after the loop.

Comment: So right an approach !! I just missed to see the option where i can place a WAIT soon after the first activity and implicitly set 8 hrs (7AM-3PM); i always thought that since i cannot determine when the midway stored procedure will complete, so then how can  I put the number of seconds within WAIT activity after which the 3PM set of jobs should trigger..

Thanks @Rakesh for the solution !